# Rails Search form Keep values after submission of drop down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropdown, ransack

Hi I have a search form like the one below. I am trying to have the drop down box retain the value selected upon submission.

```
 <%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
<th><%= f.label :model_eq, "Search By Model" %>
<%= f.select :model_eq, options_for_select([["ALL"],
    ['Gender:Condition'],
    ['Naive:Stage'],['Race:Condition']],:selected => params[:model_eq]) %></th>
<%= f.submit "Search" , :name => nil%>
<% end %>
```

I thought adding

```
:selected => params[:model_eq]
```

would keep the selected value but it doesn't. Ive also tried

```
:selected => params[:model]
```

but that also doesn't work.

Comment: Is the page reloading after the form submits, and then when it loads again, you want the dropdown to already have the selected value from the last submission?

Comment: Yes thats correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you should use `params[:q][:model_eq]` instead:

```
<%= f.select :model_eq, options_for_select([], :selected => params[:q][:model_eq]) %>
```

Comment: :model is the field I'm searching :model_eq is based on the options_for_select([]). My search function works fine so I am assuming it has a value. Do you want me to paste the HTML source code generated?

Comment: Hi @Ahk86, In order to get the value, I think we have to access like this: `params[:q][:model_eq]`. Please have a look your `params`

Comment: Hi @fongfan999 I just tried this and it worked. Have to put it inside of parenthesis though. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :)